# Unwrapping doesn't follow UV editor

Tags: uv, shaders, uv-image-editor

Oh, mighty Blender elders.

I'd like to know if this is a bug, or intended behavior.

---

**What is going on**
I have three textures with different aspect ratios. 1:1, 2:1, 3:1.
But when unwrapping, the UV map aspect ratio is **always** based on the image selected in the *shader editor*.

It seems that unwrapping depends on your *shader editor* image texture, *not* the texture in the *UV editor*.

[image]

---

So, in some cases, there's no way to match the correct aspect ratio.

Example:
2:1 in UV editor, 3:1 in *shader editor*.  And no way to match the correct ratio.

[image]

---

Additional notes:
This concerns all UV unwrap methods and projections.
*Correct aspect* ✓ doesn't work either - it only switches to 1:1 ratio.
Even after removing an image from file, Blender still unwraps in it's ratio.

---

### Question

Is this intended behavior?
Or is this a bug that should be reported?

Here is the file for testing, images included.
[image]

Comment: yes it took me time to understand until I understood that you have to select the Image Texture node. Actually as a beginner you expect the unwrap to be 1:1 whatever is the selected image in the UV Editor. I don't know why it doesn't work that way, it might cause problems that I don't get...

Comment: I've made a small mistake in my first example, that you've corrected, of course :  If you select 1:1 in the Shader Editor, and select 1:1 in the UV Editor, you'll see the correct scale, then if you select 3:1 in the UV Editor, it will be scaled 3 times on the X axis (and not 1/3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The UV scale will depend on the scale of the selected *Image Texture* node in the *Shader Editor*, but its **appearence** will be stretched in the *UV Editor*, depending on the selected image here. If you select the same image in *Shader Editor* and *UV Editor*, the UV will appear at the right scale.

If you select 1:1 in the *Shader Editor*, and select 1:1 in the *UV Editor*, you'll see the correct scale, then if you select 3:1 in the *UV Editor*, it will be scaled 3 times on the X axis.

If you choose 3:1 in the *Shader Editor* and choose 1:1 in the *UV Editor*, it will look scaled 1/3 of its X scale, if you switch to 2:1 in the *UV Editor*, it will be 2/3 of it X scale, it will only look good if you switch to 3:1 in the *UV Editor*.

It works as expected, but it surprises a bit at the beginning.