# Why are the UV objects scaled after "Project from view"

Tags: uv

I'm trying to texture an audio cassette, which is something I do for the first time.
When I select the faces where the texture should be applied on and then go for UV > Project view then the unwrapped UV objects are scaled... What do I wrong?

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UV is mapped 0 to 1.**

> One more question, if you place images (as reference or background)
> then they always have as size 5m. I scaled my reference image to 1m
> for the modelling process. If I now load the same image in the UV
> editor then the image isn't 5 times as big as the UV objects? Any
> explanation for that behavior?

In addition to @moonboots answer, and
Leaving out the image for an explanation.

The idea of a UV is to map 0 to 1 in U and V to the height and width of the image *ie* UV (0, 0) is bottom left hand corner and (1, 1) is top right hand corner.  Without an image the extents are square.

When using project from view it is making a square from the longest edge of the viewport and mapping that to the 1:1 of the UV.

Mapping to bounds extends such that the maximum and minima are exactly 0 and 1 for U and V.

[image]
*Example square extends from top to bottom of view, but not left to right, UV result is using width of viewport to make square*

[image]
*Similarly if we squeeze up the 3d view to make it extend left to right, it uses the "view square" of top to bottom.*

To put this another way, the size of the viewport also counts when projecting from view.

Comment: Thanks batFINGER!

Answer (score 5):

[Here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164191/unwrapping-doesnt-follow-uv-editor/200574#200574) a bit more precisions on how UV scale works.

When you unwrapped you probably didn't load your image in the *Image Texture* node (in the *Shader Editor*), so by default it unwrapped at a 1:1 scale. As the selected image in the *UV Editor* is not 1:1, it appears stretched.

To make sure that the UV is proportional to the mesh, select the right *Image Texture* node in the *Shader Editor*, load the right image, then unwrap again.

Before (*Image Texture* node selected but no image loaded):

[image]

After (*Image Texture* node selected with image loaded):

[image]

Comment: Hello :). I encountered this behavior [some time back](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/164191/78972) and was kinda surprised. Is it supposed to happen? Because it doesn't make much sense to me. I'd expect the UV unwrap to follow the image in UV editor.

Comment: Thanks moonboots for the tip! I wasn't aware of this. Your suggestion does work!

Comment: One more question, if you place images (as reference or background) then they always have as size 5m. I scaled my reference image to 1m for the modelling process. If I now load the same image in the UV editor then the image isn't 5 times as big as the UV objects? Any explanation for that behavior?